How do i make AWS Public node Private?
I already created a EKS cluster on a public subnet and it automatically assign IP to the node instance. I want to delete the public IP of the instance.
to achieve this i turn off the auto assign public ip option for the subnets that EKS cluster resides, but it doesn't seem to work. How do i Achieve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Turning off the auto-assign will work on the new instance, but not on the existing instance. To make the changes affects also the existing changes you need to manually remove the public address from them:

Stop the Instance:
Detach and Reattach the Network Interface
Restart the Instance

Also you should not forget to update the launch template if you're using one, and modify the network interface settings to disable “Auto-assign public IP”
